# How can I make the search bar in my wordpress site search all of the pages rather than just the blog posts?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, themes, search

When I type a word in my search bar it only returns articles from the blog section rather than pages on the site which also contain the word. How can I change that?

Comment: WordPress does search pages but, as with posts, it only searches the title and content. How are your pages built. Are you using some sort of page builder?

Comment: They are built using WPBakery.